# How can I automate specific settings in IOS?

Tags: ios, automation

I’m no new user of Apple products, but I am brand new to coding and automation on iPhone. I’ve created an automation that does *something* at a specific time of day, but that’s as far as I’ve gotten because there’s limited settings they offer without me coding anything in. I’m trying to change a specific setting in the settings app ***“Notifications->(App)->turn notifications off”*** but I’m not sure how, or even if it’s possible to do, outside of what’s already programmed in. Thanks in advance, if anyone figures it out and lends a hand. (Edit: I would automate Do Not Disturb because that seems like the simple answer, but long story short, I don’t want anyone to see banners of messages and read my texts without my phone unlocked, and Do Not Disturb doesn’t do that as far as I’m aware.)

Comment: I don't believe that you can automate individual app notification settings, but can't you just change the app to "show previews when unlocked" (which is the default) or "show previews never"?

Comment: That would completely solve my problems, I forgot those options existed. Thanks!